# Eloquent where clause for timestamp in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a table and search bar.

[image]

When user input in the search that when I grab that and query my database.

This is what I got

```
public function getLogsFromDb($q = null) {

    if (Input::get('q') != '') {
        $q = Input::get('q');
    }
    $perPage = 25;

    if ($q != '') {

        $logs = DB::table('fortinet_logs')
            ->orWhere('account_id', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('cpe_mac', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('p_hns_id', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('g_hns_id', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('data', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('created_at', 'like', '%'.$q.'%') <----
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate($perPage) 
            ->setPath('');


            //dd($logs);

        $logs->appends(['q' => $q]);

    } else {

        $logs = DB::table('fortinet_logs')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate($perPage)
            ->setPath('');
    }

    return view('telenet.views.wizard.logTable', get_defined_vars());

}
```

---

## Result

In the network tab, I kept getting

> Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown

[image]

How would one go about debugging this further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL is strict about different data types. Convert the timestamp column to text:

```
->orWhereRaw('created_at::text like ?', ['%'.$q.'%'])
```

Answer (score 1):

sanitize your inputs to avoid such problems

```
$remove = array("'","!",";","+",'|','||',"&&","}","{","[","]");
$replace = array("","","","","","","","","","","");

$q = str_replace($remove, $replace, $q);
```

Use the   new defined *$q* in your **queris**

Answer (score 0):

first step on debuggin to make an sql by tihs. And you look what is the problem for your query. 
Like this:

```
 dd($logs = DB::table('fortinet_logs')
            ->orWhere('account_id', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('cpe_mac', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('p_hns_id', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('g_hns_id', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('data', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('created_at', 'like', '%'.$q.'%')//This is the cri
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->toSql());
```

This is show for you whats the problem of this query. 
By the way, can you cast $q to daterange and can find in this range the logs.